# Regex for including only numbers and 2 special characters with space only

Tags: javascript, regex

I am preparing a regular expression validation for text box
where person can enter only 0-9,*,# each with comma seprated and non repeative.
I prepared this

```
if( ( incoming.GET_DTMF_RESPONSE.value.match(/[0-9*#]\d*$/)==null ) )
alert("DTMF WRONG"
```

where incoming is functions back and GET_DTMF_RESPONSE is textbox name

I am not good in Regex..it is accepting 0-9 and * and # thats good
but it is accepting a-z also
i want it to make non repeative numbers and no alphabet and no special character excepting #,*

Let me know how to do this

Comment: What do you mean by non-repeative?

Comment: Can you write a test list of good and bad strings ? Also you probably should start your regex with `^`.

Comment: @simonzack It is doable, though other solutions would probably be better.

Comment: @dgrin91 non repeative means I do not want that once entered number repeat again..like if i entered 1 then it should not be repeat

Comment: @dystroy i do not know how to write regular expressions..I searched and modified it little can you tell me what does ^ stands for ..so I make it more clear

Comment: @learning_programming `^` means the beginning of the string. Also please update your question with sample inputs and expected outputs.

Answer (score 5):

How about this regex

```
^(?!.*,$|.*\d{2,})(?:([\d*#]),?(?!.*\1))+$
```

For each **value** separated by comma am capturing it into group1 and then am checking if it occurs ahead using `\1`(backreference)

---

`^` marks the beginning of string

`(?!.*,$|.*\d{2,})` is a **lookahead** which would **match** further only if the string **doesn't** end with `,` or has two or more digits

In `(?:([\d*#]),?(?!.*\1))+` a single `[\d*#]` is captured in `group 1` and then we check whether there is any occurrence of it ahead in the string using `(?!.*\1)`. `\1` refers to the value in group 1.This process is repeated for each such value using `+`

`$` marks the end of string

---

For example

for Input

```
 1,2,4,6,2
```

`(?!.*,$|.*\d{2,})` checks if the string doesn't end with `,` or has two or more digits

The above lookahead only checks for the pattern but doesn't match anything.So we are still at the beginning of string

`([\d*#])` captures `1` in group 1

`(?!.*\1)` checks(not match) for `1` anywhere ahead.Since we don't find one,we move forward

Due to `+` we would again do the same thing

`([\d*#])` would now capture `2` in group 1

`(?!.*\1)` checks(not match) for `2` anywhere ahead.Since we find it,we have failed matching the text

---

works [here](http://regexhero.net/tester/)

---

But you better use non regex solution as it would be more simple and maintainable..

```
var str="1,2,4,6,6";
str=str.replace(/,/g,"");//replace all , with empty string
var valid=true;
for(var i=0;i<str.length-1;i++)
{
    var temp=str.substr(i+1);
    if(temp.indexOf(str[i])!=-1)valid=false;
}
//valid is true or false depending on input
```

Comment: thnks dear..its working..but one thing what i want that it should not be like 11 only one digit or spcl character with comma seprate..

Comment: can you pls little bit explain me so i can understand and make change if needed?

Comment: you are better off using non regex solution given at the end of my ans as it would be simple and more maintainable..also if this ans solves your problem,you can accept it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
^(?:([0-9#*])(?!(?:,.)*,\1)(?:,|$))+$
```

Comment: you are missing `.*` in lookahead..:P

Comment: @Anirudh: crap! Chars must be non repeated for all the string?

Comment: as you told it is repeating # and * its working fine :) but i do not need that..thanks you